# Home tab not rendered properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I noticed that the home tab on the new navigation bar is not rendered properly sometimes. It can be simulated, but it also occurs sometimes random it seems.

1. Select the `newest` tab
2. Refresh the website (I use F5)
3. Notice that the `newest` tab is still selected (which seems okay)
4. Select the `home` tab

The `home` tab looks like this:

[image]

Browser: Firefox 41.0.2
OS: Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

A fix is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.10.27.3789` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.27.2908` on sites)